# Check if two char from array are present(together) in a string

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of characters -

```
$operators = array('%', '*', '+', '-', '@');
```

and a string for eg-

```
$text = '%@';
```

How can I find if the string contains two values from the array in concatenation -

Like `$text = %test%` - valid, but `$text = %+test` should fail (`$concat = TRUE`).

This is what I've tried -

```
$concat = FALSE;
foreach ($operators as $op) {
  $opPosition[$op] = strpos($text, $op);
  // Here I need to check if any two values of
  // $opPosition are neighbours, set the $concat variable to TRUE.
}
```

How do I make a check for `$opPosition` or is this the only way what I'm trying ?

Comment: Dig a little into regular expressions. I think that this would be helpful: `preg_match_all()`

Comment: try `preg_match("/[%\*\+\-@]{2,}/", $text);`

Comment: @bansi As I have a whole array to check from, thought the regex would a long string to configure

Comment: Well the above regex seems to be handling most of the cases

Comment: @bansi Wouldn't your regex fail for `%+test`?

Comment: @Justinas no it works, just can't find a string which will not work - Bansi, can you add that as an answer ?

Comment: @jitendrapurohit By your test `%+test` should fail, but it matches.

Comment: By _should fail_ I actually meant $concat variable should be set to TRUE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) like below.

```
// $concat will be 1 for any match
$concat = preg_match("/[%\*\+\-@]{2,}/", $text);
```

You can find the explanation for the regular expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/JtU2Qd/1)

Note: `$concat` will be 0 even if some error occurs. You may need to use `==` operator.

*Edit:* if your operators are in and array, or need flexibility to add, change or remove operators without disturbing the regular expression you can use the following code.

```
$text = "test%+";
$operators = array('%', '*', '+', '-', '@');
// create regular expression by imploding the array to string and using
// preg_quote to Quote regular expression characters
$expression = preg_quote(implode('', $operators), '/');
$concat = preg_match("/[$expression]{2,}/", $text);
```

Reference for [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php)

Demo [here](https://eval.in/697176)

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use this code section to get your desired output -

```
$operators = array('%', '*', '+', '-', '@');
$text = '%test%';
$end = substr($text,-1);
$start = substr($text, 0,1);
if(($start == $end) && in_array($start, $operators) == 1){
  echo "valid";
}else{
  echo "Not Valid";
}
```